# Apereo CAS Protocol: is it allowed for the CAS Server to change the URL?

Tags: cas, apereo

According to the CAS Webflow (https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/images/cas_flow_diagram.png):

After successful authentication the CAS server sends a redirect to the browser that contains a Cookie and a URL (Location-Header). This URL appears to be the originally requested protected URL with the addition of a ticket Parameter (containing the Service Ticket). Is it a violation of the CAS protocol if the CAS server adds more parameters to this URL?

In my actual case the user selects a language from a dropdown, when authenticating at the CAS server. This lang-Parameter is then submitted along with username and password and the CAS server simply appends it to the URL he sends in the redirect as something like "&lang=fr-FR".

The Apereo Java client runs into a validation failure because of that parameter. This is because the Service URL to validate the Service Ticket for contains this lang parameter. The CAS server then does not validate the Service Ticket, because it was issued for a different URL (without lang parameter).

So my question is: does this particular CAS Server violate the CAS protocol?

Or would the Apereo CAS client be expected to deal with this by stripping off all unknown request parameters when constructing the Service URL for validation?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: does this particular CAS Server violate the CAS protocol?

Yes.

From the CAS Protocol, `service` for the login endpoint is:

> service [OPTIONAL] - the URL of the application the client is trying to access.

From the CAS Protocol, `service` for the validation endpoint is:

> service [REQUIRED] - the identifier of the service for which the ticket was issued

Also specified under error codes,

> INVALID_SERVICE - the ticket provided was valid, but the service specified did not match the service associated with the ticket. CAS MUST invalidate the ticket and disallow future validation of that same ticket.

Comment: I believe the issue here is not the service parameter, but the location header in the redirect. I struggle to find a specification what this location header must contain. It is certainly not the originally requested URL, because at the very least it contains the ticket parameter. And, in this case, also the lang parameter.